# PHP's garbage collector does not work?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I have Laravel based application which run on top of php 7.0

I have problem with queue workers `php artisan queue:work --daemon` in the sense that it is consuming memory over time.

The basic code which starts processing looks like this (only important part is shown)

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

class TaskCronJoib extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
   use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

   private $type;

   public function __construct(string $type)
   {
      $this->type = $type;
   }

    public function handle()
    {
        $handler = app()->make(HandlerFactory::class)->get($this->type);
        $handler->process();
    }
}
```

I've tested (and it works) that when I add gc_collect_cycles() at the end of `handle()` it consumer far less memory over time.

Like this

I've tested (and it works) that when I add gc_collect_cycles() at the end of `handle()` it consumer far less memory over time.

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $handler = app()->make(HandlerFactory::class)->get($this->type);
        $handler->process();
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
```

Laravel's workers are working indefinitely, so it is usual case when every php process is working 6 hours or event 12 hours. I use `php artisan queue:restart` in crontab and supervisor to restart processes periodically to avoid memory consumption anyway.

TLDR: why adding gc_collect_cycles() causes PHP to consume memory far less?

Garbage collector is enabled by default

```
php -i | grep enable_gc                                                
zend.enable_gc => On => On
```

There are NO calls like 
    gc_disable();
    ini_set('zend.enable_gc', false);

Comment: [It is also possible to force the collection of cycles even if the possible root buffer is not full yet. For this, you can use the gc_collect_cycles() function. This function will return how many cycles were collected by the algorithm. _The rationale behind the ability to turn the mechanism on and off, and to initiate cycle collection yourself, is that some parts of your application could be highly time-sensitive._](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, a `--daemon` truly is a persistent request so it doesn't clear memory by default.  If the handle() is short lived, I'd consider a `queue:listen` instead since this will end the request after the task is completed which would automatically free up memory.  If there is a chance that two of these tasks may coincide together (aka very long tasks that take a long time to complete) then a gc_collect_cycles() and --daemon flag would probably suffice.

However, there is performance overhead associated with manually dumping the gc cycles.  Therefore, doing it too often can yield performance hits--if handle() is a short lived process, it might not be worth introducing a gc_collect_cycles().  Depends on the architecture and what's going on in the background.  If it's a short lived process that is rapidly and constantly called, this could be a scenario for keeping a persistent daemon and manually dumping the gc instead of bootstrapping Laravel up and down.  Really just depends.

gc_collect_cycles() would just dump the cycles at a higher frequency instead of automatically.  Typically, for single requests, it waits until an arbitrary number of zvals, 10,000, before it automatically checks what can be dumped from the root buffer.  Or it automatically handles it at the end of a request.  The number can be changed via PHP config and recompiling.

PHP 7.3 will also be introducing some improvements to the garbage collection (for certain scenarios, not in general) so be sure to update PHP if possible.

Sources:

[Laravel Daemon Queue Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245190/laravel-daemon-queue-memory-leak)

http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to remove the guest session file, that may help:

```
    $c = 0;
    $files = File::files(storage_path().'/framework/sessions');

    foreach ($files as $f) {
        $file_content = file_get_contents($f);

        $arrFileData = unserialize($file_content);
        $dtCreated = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($arrFileData['_sf2_meta']['u']);
        $dtNow = Carbon::now();
        $diffInHours = $dtNow->diffInHours($dtCreated);
        //if file is older than 2h & not found 'login_web_' then remove file
        if ($diffInHours > 2 && strpos($file_content, 'login_web_') === false) {
            $c++;
            @unlink($f);
        }
    }
    echo "Clear unnecessary sessions: ".$c;
```